# How to get the html code?Jquery html() and outhtml prop is not what I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is：

```
 <div id="TemplateMode" style="display: none;"> 
        <tr class='trStudent'>
            <td><input name="aa" type="text"  /></td> 
            <td><input name="bb" type="text"/></td> 
        </tr> 
    </div>
```

Now  I want to get the template content string like this:

```
  <tr class='trStudent'>
            <td><input name="aa" type="text"  /></td> 
            <td><input name="bb" type="text"/></td> 
           <td><input name="cc" type="text"/></td> 
        </tr>
```

I try to use $('#TemplateMode').html(),but it seems the result is

```
  <input name="aa" type="text" /> 
  <input name="bb" type="text"/>
   <input name="c" type="text"/>
```

I try to use outhtml prop,but it still not work.How to fix it?

Comment: `$('#TemplateMode').html()` won't change anything ... `outhtml prop` what is this?

Comment: `<tr>` isn't a valid child of `<div>`. Could use a `<script type="text/myTemplate">` and it won't get rendered as html or evaluated as script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use raw JavaScript's **[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('TemplateMode').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="TemplateMode" style="display: none;">
  <tr class='trStudent'>
    <td><input name="aa" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="bb" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

However, note that the `<tr>` element was **not** rendered. This is because you have **invalid markup**, which you can validate through the **[W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/)**.

Note that a `<tr>` element is **[not a valid child of `<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)**; the only valid parents for `<tr>` are `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` (in addition to the rare valid parent `<table>`).

What's particularly interesting about `table > tr` is that the missing `<tbody>` will be inferred, and automatically added into the DOM for you.

Turning the `<div>` element into a `<table>` (resulting in valid markup) shows a successful output of the `<tr>` element, and also shows the automatic creation of the supporting `<tbody>`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('TemplateMode').innerHTML);
```

```html
<table id="TemplateMode" style="display: none;">
  <tr class='trStudent'>
    <td><input name="aa" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="bb" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I have already has an tdbody in the other table,It seems I can use tr:last to get what I want.

Comment: **Every** table not only *should* have a `<tbody>`, but actually **requires** one. You have invalid markup as it stands, which is why you cannot target the `<tr>` element. You should really fix your markup rather than attempt to solve the problems with hacky workarounds.